# Unittest of Prism.DialogService

Tags: wpf, prism

i use Prism.Wpf with Nert.Core 3.xxx and i would like tp use XUnit as testing Framework.
Is there any idea how to test Dialogs?
In my application i use the following Code snippet.

public DelegateCommand CustomerSelectionCommand =>
           _customerSelectionCommand ?? (_customerSelectionCommand = new DelegateCommand(async () =>
           {
               var parameters = new DialogParameters
               {
                   { "Title", "Kunden Auswahldialog" }
               };
               UnsubscribeEvents();
               var dialogService = _container.Resolve();

```
           dialogService.ShowDialog("CustomerSelectionDialog", parameters, CloseCustomerSelectionCallback);
       }));
```

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 0):

> `var dialogService = _container.Resolve()`

This is just bad. So lets assume, you set `_dialogService` in the constructor... then, in your test, inject a `Mock<IDialogService>` or a handcoded variant, if you prefer, and call the `CustomerSelectionCommand` on your view model-subject-under-test. Afterwards, inspect the mock whether the expected `ShowDialog` call arrived.

Alternatively, setup you mock to call the passed callback and check just the view model's state after the command.

Anyway, what you do *not* want to do, is write a test for `DialogService` as suggested by the question title, simply because you do not need to. It's not your code, and the library has its own set of unit tests for its classes.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late answer. It seems that it will work…..Thanks Peter